# How to map (compose) multiple non-collection in functions over collection?

Tags: clojure

I would like to pass a collection through series of non-collection functions. It could be achieved by using map multiple times. How to do it more concisely and clojure/functional programming idiomatic way:

```
(defn my-processor [coll]
  (let [get-text (fn [element] (:text element))
        sanitize (fn [element] (string/trim element))
        to-int (fn [element] (Integer. element))]
    (map to-int (map sanitize (map get-text coll))))) ; <-- this line
```

`(my-processor [{:text "123"} {:text "456"}]) ; => (123 456))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work:
`(map (comp to-int sanitize get-text) coll)`

Comment: Yes, and here you don’t even need the named functions: `(map #(-> % :text str/trim Integer/parseInt) coll)`.

Comment: Which in turn could be done either as `(map (comp Integer/parseInt str/trim :text) coll)` or even `(def processor (comp Integer/parseInt str/trim :text)) (map processor coll)`

Comment: @slipset no, static Java methods are not Clojure functions, so you can't actually use `Integer/parseInt` with `comp`.

Comment: @NathanDavis you're right. How boring. `read-string` would work, but that's opening another can of worms I guess...